# 18.04 Server USB 3.0 and eSata

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb

I'm new to ubuntu, and I'm still getting my server setup.  I am having issues getting my USB 3.0 and eSata connects on my case to function- it doesn't seem that these ports are even being detected.  I've updated grub, edited in iommu=soft into  ‘GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=’

Not sure where to go from here,  thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:

```
scott@lits-server:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for scott: 
lits-server                 
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Z87E-ITX
       vendor: ASRock
       physical id: 0
       serial: E80-38005200289
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P2.10
          date: 10/04/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: a
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
          configuration: level=1
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: b
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
          slot: CPUSocket
          size: 3389MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: c
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:1
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: d
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: e
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: BLS8G3D1609ES2LX0.
             vendor: Conexant (Rockwell)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 17012123
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: BLS8G3D1609ES2LX0.
             vendor: Conexant (Rockwell)
             physical id: 1
             serial: 16111716
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:e8000000-f30fffff
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK110 [GeForce GTX 780]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:26 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GK110 HDMI Audio
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f3080000-f3083fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:24 memory:f3120000-f312ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-39-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=14 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB Keyboard
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@3:4
                   version: 64.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=90mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB Optical Mouse
                   vendor: Primax Electronics, Ltd
                   physical id: e
                   bus info: usb@3:e
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-39-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f313b000-f313b00f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 05
             serial: bc:5f:f4:cd:06:8b
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: irq:25 memory:f3100000-f311ffff memory:f3139000-f3139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f3138000-f31383ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-39-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.05
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: BCM20702A0
                      vendor: Broadcom Corp
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@1:1.5
                      version: 1.12
                      serial: 240A646F1832
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f3130000-f3133fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 memory:f3200000-f34fffff
           *-network
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Limited
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:f3400000-f3407fff memory:f3200000-f33fffff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f3137000-f31373ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-39-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.05
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Z87 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:27 ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f3136000-f31367ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f3135000-f31350ff ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10EZEX-60M
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1A01
             serial: WD-WCC3FC45RNU9
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=7ddebabc-30a0-4a83-84b9-39c0b9de0f03 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10EZEX-75M
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 1A01
             serial: WD-WCC3F7NPARKD
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=f8270852
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 5a11-2da1
                size: 98MiB
                capacity: 100MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-04-17 15:12:45 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 3aeaf1c4-e5ec-dd48-a14f-8b4b937aa268
                size: 931GiB
                capacity: 931GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-04-17 15:12:46 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000DM003-1CH1
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: CC44
             serial: Z1D46JX9
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=686fd8f2
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdc1
                version: 3.1
                serial: c41f13aa-af83-164b-bf2c-8538c37e313d
                size: 931GiB
                capacity: 931GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-04-30 15:40:31 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume state=clean
     *-scsi:3
          physical id: 4
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10EALX-229
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdd
             version: 1H15
             serial: WD-WCATR7957230
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=6e8dac5c
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdd1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 648b08bb-7e08-1344-8b7b-b81e9313e78d
                size: 467GiB
                capacity: 467GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-12-03 01:45:47 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdd2
                version: 3.1
                serial: aa91de31-aa00-0643-90ae-ee4a85994ef0
                size: 464GiB
                capacity: 464GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-12-02 23:24:31 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume state=clean
     *-scsi:4
          physical id: 5
          logical name: scsi5
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD2000FYYZ-0
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sde
             version: 1K03
             serial: WD-WMC1P0E7TMSH
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=700b321d-97d9-4c74-9da1-cac298f8ef5f logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: BIOS Boot partition
                vendor: EFI
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sde1
                serial: 36504fc0-0ec1-430b-87ab-0396d25a48b3
                capacity: 1023KiB
                capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sde2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 8a933266-eebb-11e8-aced-bc5ff4cd068b
                size: 1863GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2018-11-22 20:03:08 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-11-22 20:06:29 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2018-11-26 17:38:17 state=mounted
```

Edit: I don't think the USB3 and eSata ports work because they don't.

Comment: Check your BIOS to make sure that your USB and SATA ports are enabled. Why did you add iommu=soft? Edit your question to show me the output of `sudo lshw`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I tried iommu=soft as it was a potential solution I found during research.

Comment: I'm confused. The lshw output shows USB and SATA ports, and even disks with NTFS and EXT4 partitions. What leads you to believe that they're not working?

Comment: Your BIOS is way old. See https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z87E-ITX/index.asp#BIOS for updates that might solve your problem.